# Debug tells me to switch setOnClickListener with setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio

When debugging, the console tells me I should use `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener` because I have an `AdapterView`. This error comes up when I press a button and that button is supposed to transition me to another activity. I have tried to implement `setOnItemClick` and import `android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;` and I still get red lines under my code. What am I doing wrong?

Original Java Code for button action

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class NewLocation extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_location);
        findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(NewLocation.this, RoomDescription.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

Debug Error

```
07-11 11:37:45.281    2141-2141/com.customledsupply.ledaudit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.customledsupply.ledaudit, PID: 2141
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.customledsupply.ledaudit/com.customledsupply.ledaudit.RoomDescription}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
            at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:783)
            at com.customledsupply.ledaudit.RoomDescription.onCreate(RoomDescription.java:17)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

New Java Code for Button Activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class NewLocation extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_location);
        findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(NewLocation.this, RoomDescription.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: the error suggests that you have a `ListView` or `GridView` with id button4

Comment: the button is connected to a page that has a `ListView` could that be it?

Comment: no, mostly you assigned by mistake the same id to listview and button

Comment: Try to set on item click listener on the activity since it's action bar activity and I'm guessing the button is inside the bar.

Comment: Here is a picture of my navigation editor for reference  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B80RkK4mIcD4YjBYWlNSdTk0Qnc

Comment: The id for the button and the listview are different and the button is not inside the bar

Comment: btw the stacktrace concers OldLocation and not NewLocation

Comment: sorry see my edit for the correct debug error for that section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting an `OnClickListener` on an `AdapterView` doesn't make sense because generally its the children of the `AdapterView` that should be clicked (e.g. rows of a `ListView`). That's why it's telling you to set an `OnItemClickListener` instead.

When you do that, your anonymous inner class needs to change because `OnItemClickListener` does not have a method with the signature `void onClick(View v)`. You need

```
findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize the inside had to change.