# why "Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView" error getting for image button in android?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener, android-imagebutton

I am getting an error like following in logcat when i use **setonclicklistener** on ImageButton

**FATAL EXCEPTION: main**

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emsys.emapp/com.emsys.emapp.StockActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead

here is my code

```
ib2= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        ib2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View view) {
                                       Intent intent1=new Intent(view.getRootView().getContext(),StockActivity.class);
                                       startActivity(intent1);
                                   }
                               }
        );
```

Comment: This code is written in your activity or adapter?

Comment: in my activity, inside oncreate method

Comment: it is AppCompatActivity

Comment: That is why you are getting the problem, just move that code inside the adapter getView() method if you are using listView or onBindViewHolder() if you are using RecyclerViewAdapter.

Comment: If you have doubts let me know i will post a detailed answer

Comment: please post a detailed answer. i am not using listview or recyclerview. this is just a simple imagebutton on a blank activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118898/discussion-between-manikanta-and-irfan).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug tells me to switch setOnClickListener with setOnItemClickListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359639/debug-tells-me-to-switch-setonclicklistener-with-setonitemclicklistener)

Answer (score -1):

So here is your answer:

Change your content layout as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"

        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton2" />



    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton4" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is your activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;



/**
 * Created by Mani on 02/08/16.
 */
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton ib2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.asdf);
        ib2= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        ib2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1=new Intent(MenuActivity.this,YourActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Replace YourActivity with stockActivity or whatever it is.

Comment: what changes you made in this?